# Issue with Aeson or Wai.JSON QuasiQuoter -- Converts 0.0 to 0

Tags: haskell, aeson, hspec

I am using `Test.Hspec.Wai.JSON` to check the return value of my api endpoints. I noticed that whenever i create a json with a value of `0.0`, when the test runs, it converts it to `0` (Int) and if the api returns `0.0`, the test fails.

```
let  j = [json|{"test":0.0}|]
request "GET" "some_url" [("Content-Type", "application/json")] ""
        `shouldRespondWith` j {matchStatus = 200}

   body mismatch:
     expected: {"test":0}  ---> this is the issue (0.0 has become 0)
     but got:  {"test":0.0}
```

I am not that advanced in Haskell to figure out where in the library code this is happening. I looked at the source code for `Test.Hspec.Wai.JSON` and it seems to be relying on `Aeson.QQ` so not really sure the source of the issue. This is [Test.Hspec.Wai.JSON source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-wai-json-0.6.1/docs/src/Test-Hspec-Wai-JSON.html#json) and this is the [Aeson.QQ Source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-qq-0.8.1/docs/src/Data-Aeson-QQ.html#aesonQQ)

Due to this, my work around has been to write a `FromJSON` instance to parse the entire response and check against the filled out record. This is a bit tedious.

Any suggestions as to what in the library code is causing this? And how to fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suspect appears to be this line of `Data.Aeson.QQ`:

```
toExp (JsonNumber n) = [|Number (fromRational $(return $ LitE $ RationalL (toRational n)))|]
```

It converts the number to a `Rational`, converts that to a Haskell expression, and then has the resulting expression then turn it back into a `Number`. This ends up discarding the fact that it was `0.0` rather than `0`.

This would not normally be a problem, as Aeson correctly defines `==` to make `Number`s with equal values equal. This becomes an actual problem with `Test.Hspec.Wai.JSON`; the way it works is that it encodes the object back into a `ByteString` and expects it to match it exactly.

While `Data.Aeson.QQ` is the root cause of your problem, I would not hold it to blame. Instead, `Test.Hspec.Wai.JSON` should not be serializing JSON objects and expecting their representations to be equivalent. Rather, it should be deserializing the actual response and comparing the decoded objects for equality. (After all, floating-point/integer isn’t the only possible problem. It also wouldn’t be able to handle object keys being reordered.) I’m not familiar with Hspec, so I’m not sure how you’d make it do that.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I guess I will just stick to parsing the entire record for now. Btw, for whatever reason `json` seems to work regardless of the order of the keys as long as it is a flat object and not an array.

Comment: @Ecognium: The order of the keys doesn’t matter in your case because you’re using Aeson both in your tests and in the implementation of the web service, and Aeson will normalize the order of the keys during serialization. However, if you were using something other than Aeson in your web service which disagreed with Aeson in how the key orders should be, your test would say the responses differ when they were semantically equivalent.